# CSS Not Working On Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I am having a website here - http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/

I am going through css not loading issue I have checked several other questions online to figure out this . But This one looks weird one

There is not Javascript error at Console . In Network Tab in Inspect element everything is loading including my style.css file

I am unable to know the exact issue as there is no js error and all css is loading in Network Tab of inspect element

Can anyone suggest me the solution for this I will be greatly thankful

Here are three files that can show the Correct images of header , footer and other content

www.jjdealsandsteals.us/1.PNG

www.jjdealsandsteals.us/3.PNG

www.jjdealsandsteals.us/2.PNG

Comment: "Night Club" template with a children's party as a background. Somehow that feels wrong. ;o)  Anyway, I see at least *some* CSS being loaded, so please add the relevant parts to your question and please describe clearly which part of the result is different than you expected. It's hard for us to judge, since we don't have the mental picture of your desired end result.

Comment: in the Chrome developer console, Network tab, there are 2 CSS that are not found: http://74.208.43.187:8080/fonts.googleapis.com/css2f8a.css?family=Lusitana:400,700

Comment: @GolezTrol LOL our names...

Comment: Great names look alike. ;)

Comment: Let me arrange the pic that will show how the menu bar should show . the menu is not loading properly and i am also going to check the css that are not loading

Comment: Here are three files that can show the images of header , footer and other content

http://jjdealsandsteals.us/1.PNG
http://jjdealsandsteals.us/3.PNG
http://jjdealsandsteals.us/2.PNG

Comment: And There is no CSS Error in Network Tab these are Fonts error  and i think that does not create any problem

Comment: I don't think you'll get a lot of help by throwing us a problem and expecting anyone takes the time to solve it. Ask questions and you'll get answers. If you find the problem and are not sure why it happened, ask.

Comment: ok Thanks  I got it. Actually Everything was working fine 1 day ago . But the last update to website created some problem .In last update I made changes to Admin Panel not to front end .

Let me check some thing more and tell you in 5 mins

Comment: I have having separate header and footer files and these contains css files I have replace these css files with header and footer files from one of my backups where it is working fine even then its not working

Comment: What could be possible reasons for this thing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your css doesn't load because it is not found.. see the console errors:

```
    http://74.208.43.187:8080/fonts.googleapis.com/css5c84.css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://74.208.43.187:8080/fonts.googleapis.com/css2f8a.css?family=Lusitana:400,700 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):58 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
```

Be sure to provide the real working path and check for console errors.. you will need to fix:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href='../../../../fonts.googleapis.com/css2f8a.css?family=Lusitana:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='../../../../fonts.googleapis.com/css5c84.css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/style/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/style/color.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/style/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style/ie.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <link href="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/style/slider.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/js/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/js/sample.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/public/style/neo.css">
```

Comment: If you see There are no particular Console Errors Why you are checking the Fonts errors . They didn't put any problem 

and for all paths I have given the Proper paths using base_url in php 

And for $(...).autocomplete is not a function . Do you think it can block the css to load if yes . Then let me clerify you that the autocomplete is only used in homepage you can use any other page from the menu like

http://74.208.43.187:8080/partylifeusa/Home/ListingType

and error is still exist on this page . There is no autocomplete error on this page and Fonts never create any problem

Comment: For You I have Removed the Font Files Lines of Code and Also Removed the Autocomplete JS Code 

Still Error Is Same

Comment: Can You Please Suggest any other option as css is loading fine as style is defined in style.css and it is loading fine

Answer (score 1):

Your fonts aren't loading because they're trying to reference Google Fonts locally (../../../../fonts.googleapis.com).  They should be absolutely referenced (://fonts.googleapis.com).

Comment: I think Fonts don't put any effect on it even after Removing the fonts code lines this thing exist

Comment: I know it doesn't fix your whole problem, but it's one of the problems with your CSS calls.  As for the menu, style.css isn't applying its main-nav rules for some reason.  Could be server configuration, maybe?

Comment: Ok First I am going to remove that font problem so that I does not create any other person to figure that

  And for server configuration I am not sure But it was working fine 1 day ago

Comment: I have Removed the Font File Lines of Codes But Error Is same

Comment: Can You Please Suggest any other option as css is loading fine as style is defined in style.css and it is loading fine